# Efficient String replace-all strategy in Groovy with "body"

Tags: string, performance, groovy, replace

Simple question:

Which is the most efficient way of performing a substituion like:

```
"Some tekst with a link like this <ref>linktekst</ref>"
```

To

```
"Some tekst with a link like this <a href="linktekst">linktekst</a>"
```

In groovy?

There can easily be more than one tag in the text, that should be substituted, and *linktext* is of course the body of the `<ref>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.replaceAll`:

```
def s = "Some tekst with a link like this <ref>linktekst</ref> and <ref>link2</ref>"
s = s.replaceAll "<ref>(.+?)</ref>", '<a href="$1">$1</a>'
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :) Wasn't aware of the $-placeholder syntax!